# AggregateProjection cannot support aggregates that are soft-deleted Marten db and C#

Tags: c#, marten

I am trying to activate snapShot and soft delete for an aggregate in marten db. and when I run the the project I get a run time error saying : 'AggregateProjection cannot support aggregates that are soft-deleted'.

.net version : 8

Marten version: 6.3

```
public static class StoreOptionsExtensions
{
    public static void ConfigureEventStore(this StoreOptions options)
    {
        options.Schema.For<MyAggregate>().SoftDeleted();
        options.Projections.Snapshot<MyAggregate>(SnapshotLifecycle.Inline);
    }
}
```

and the error is :

`AggregateProjection cannot support aggregates that are soft-deleted`

my question is that, Is it possible to have both snapshots and softDelete activated? and if yes how should I implement it?